# OpenELEC, non-root user, home directory, SSH

Tags: ssh, permissions, root, home, openelec

I'm running OpenELEC on Raspberry Pi
As you know, directory `/storage` is a shared home folder between user `root` and user `openelec`
This makes a problem when you want to setup ssh key authentication for root
Because for that, you will have to change the owner of `/storage` from `openelec` to `root`, and change it's permission to `755` so that it won't be writable by non-root users including `openelec`
In other words, user `openelec` won't be able to write to his own home directory

I have done that, and I want to make sure that wouldn't make a problem
When I look at the output of `ps aux` I can't find any process running by `openelec` user (so that it needs to write to his own home folder)
(the main process `xbmc` is running by root too)

Now I have several questions:

1. Why does that user `openelec` exist in the first place?
2. Why it's using a common home directory with root?
3. Why `/storage` is not owned by root by default?
4. Have I done/understood something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I use OpenELEC as well on my Rasp. Pi and have never had issues with the use of `/storage` having it owned by `/root`. I use SSH keys to get into the system when I need to.

I've never seen anything actually using the `openelec` user account either.